# ASP.NET MVC User based Privileges for Controller Actions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization, user-roles

I have application where I want to grant or prohibited  the roles to access the Controller.

Admin can change the the privilege of roles in roles management.

[below is pic of role management where admin can change the privilege](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nodft.png)

How to apply Authorization on Controllers based on these dynamically changing privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33100062/2046565) is exactly what you need.
You can create custom policies, in your case a policy per controller where you get the roles from the database in your custom policy.